# How to calculate the space and time complexity for following code?

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

The code works like:

If the input is [1, 2, 3, 4]

and the code does - [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [3, 5, 7] -> [8, 2]

step 1: 1+2 = 3; 2+3 = 5; 3+4 = 7 i.e [3, 5, 7]

Step 2: 3+5 = 8; 5+7 = 12 i.e 12%10 which is 2 so final is [8, 2]

The final output should be "82"

Following is the code:

```
    def getEncryptedNumber(numbers):
        for ind in range(len(numbers)):
            if numbers[ind] > 10:
                return ""
    
        if len(numbers) == 2:
            ans = str(numbers[0]) +  str(numbers[1])
            return ans
    
        ans_lst = []
        while len(ans_lst) != 2:
            ans_lst = []
            for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
                lst_two = (numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]) % 10
                ans_lst.append(lst_two)
            numbers = ans_lst
    
        if len(ans_lst) == 2:
            ans = str(ans_lst[0]) + str(ans_lst[1])
            return ans
```

Comment: what's your question? ... what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Hey, there is nothing wrong in the code, I just want to know it's complexity

Comment: what does that mean?